# insert data to AWS MySQL using Node.js code

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi

I wanted to insert data from raspberry pi 2 (having Node.js application running on it) to AWS RDS ((MySQL). 
I am able to connect to AWS MySQL instance using command prompt and MySQL workbench. Now I just want to push some data to AWS using node.js program. Can any body guide how to connect the AWS MySQL database from Node.js application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **node-mysql** ([link here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)). Install-it first and you will be able to insert datas into your database.

Warning : Make sure to configure database and security group to allow connections from outside.

Comment: Please validate the link.